# How to Create Download Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the best way to create a download link? Is there a better way than the following?

I was thinking of using `link_to "Download", :controller => ..., :action => ...", :id => ...` in the view.

Adding `match /documents/download/:id => documents#download` to routes.rb

And in the controller:

```
def download
  send_file ...
end
```

Also, I'd like, if possible, for the user to remain on the same page as the link.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending very large, or dynamically generated files?

Comment: @Danny Rockets: Yes, the files are dynamically generated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392003/how-to-download-a-file-from-rails-application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I add the download action as a restful route in a resources block. Here's typical code for me:

routes.rb

```
  resources :things do
    member do
      get :download
    end
  end
```

model:

```
  has_attached_file :document,
    :path => ':rails_root/assets/documents/:id/:basename.:extension'
  attr_protected :document_file_name, :document_content_type, :document_file_size
```

controller:

```
  def download
    send_file @thing.document.path, :type => 'application/pdf', :filename => @thing.permalink
  end
```

view:

```
  <%= link_to 'Download', download_thing_path(@thing) %>
```

This keeps the user on the same page, and just initiates the download with my suggested name (I use permalink).

What do you mean by dynamically generated? Are they uploaded by you or created by your application on the fly?

Comment: I interpreted the question to mean anything not statically available like a preloaded icon image or license text file. In my case (text, doc, pdf) files are generated and uploaded by a group of users; the dynamic aspect comes from the ad hoc nature of the uploads.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, then your :type in your download action could be @thing.document_content_type instead of the 'application/pdf' in my example.

Answer (score 2):

You could just have your download logic in your show action and give it:

```
<%= link_to "Download", document_path(document) %>
```

I'm pretty sure that the :controller / :action / :id method of linking is frowned upon.

Comment: ammend the route to be: match /documents/download/:id => documents#download :as => :document

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a Download .mp3 link and used in my .htaccess file.

```
<Files *.mp3>
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

I found this to be easier than any other solution.