# how to download a file from application resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What i need is the ability to download a file which is not stored in the database but in one of application folders. lets say that the path of this file might look like this:

```
application_name/log/important_resources/file.txt
```

In my app I want one place where this file can be downloaded.
I tried

```
File.open(path)
```

but it fails to give me anything, literally just open the file and does nothing.

EDIT

Where i need this feature is one of the models

Comment: You can create download action and use send_file as Slicedpan suggest in your controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164063/file-download-link-in-rails might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `send_file` in your controller action to send files to the client. [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file)

Comment: you can't use this function from a model, can you explain why you can't use it from a controller?