# How to create a download button (link) for a local image (png)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my `Ruby on Rails 4` application I want to provide the user with a download for a png image.

Firstly, **where** would this png need to be placed:

- /public
- /assets/images

Secondly, **how** would I do that?
I've tried what the 2nd answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164063/file-download-link-in-rails?rq=1) says, and I am getting this error:
`No route matches [GET] "/public/diagram.png"`

The implementation of the above answer:
At my **view**:
`<%= link_to "DOWNLOAD", "/public/diagram.png" %>`

The **controller**:

```
class ControllerNamesController < ApplicationController 
// other actions defined: index, show, create, new, edit, update, destroy
def download_png
    send_file(
        "#{Rails.root}/public/diagram.png",
        filename: "diagram.png",
        type: "application/png"
    )
end
```

Τhe **routes** file (has all the controllers defined like this):

```
resources :ControllerName  
get "ControllerName/download_png", as: :download
```

Comment: try to use path <%= link_to "DOWNLOAD", "/diagram.png" %> when your image is in public folder

Comment: @NitinJ: Great, this worked. But it loaded the image into the browser. How can I make it open a download dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

## view

```
<%= link_to "Download" ,:action => :download %>
```

## controller

```
def download
    send_file '/home/blog/downloads/away.png',:type=>"application/png", :x_sendfile=>true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For the question,putting the images in **/public** would be fine. And for the error which you are getting,this is the problem

You are just putting the `path` of the image file in the `link_to` helper while it expects a route.

Try changing it to

```
<%= link_to "DOWNLOAD", home_download_png_url %>
```

**Edit**

Can't think why it didn't worked.Okay,as @nithinJ suggested you can use

```
<%= link_to "DOWNLOAD", "/diagram.png" %>
```

And as you mentioned,you want it to be downloded rather than opening in the new brower,you could do this in the controller

```
send_file '#{Rails.root}/public/diagram.png', type: 'image/png', disposition: 'attachment'
```

For more info,see **[send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file)**.

Comment: Adding this, yields this error: `undefined local variable or method `cr12s_download_png_url' for ..class`

Comment: Added the new send_file, but it still opened in the same tab.

Comment: Are you sure the controller is being called and the file isn't just being served by the server? What is the generated link?

Answer (score 0):

do this in `route.rb`

```
get "home/download_png" , as: :download
```

in view, change this

```
<%= link_to "DOWNLOAD", download_path %>
```

Comment: I am getting `Couldn't find ControllerName with id=download_png`.

Comment: show your routes file and also include `home` controller.

Comment: I've added some more info as you've asked, but I cannot post the whole controller here, it's not an open source project :/ (I'll try to post as many information as you request, but also not posting many information)

Comment: put this line`get "cr12s/download_png", as: :download` above `resources :ControllerName`

Comment: Made a typo there, the `cr12s` is `ControllerNames`.  It still opens into the browser. :/