# Open PDF in file system using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, pdf

I'm making frontend with Angular and backend with rails.
I have a function to render pdf and return url of it.
PDF is populated in format of  `/public/rendered/*.pdf`.

After I make the pdf I call a function called `openInNewTab`

```
window.open(response.data["path"].split("/")[1]);
```

However, it is giving me an error saying

```
No route matches [GET] "/public/rednered/8-64dde64b-5548-4596-96a0-27b11ca51e2e.pdf"
```

I confirm that the pdf file exists. How do I show a pdf file in new tab?

Comment: Javascript isn't the problem.  Problem is your ruby controller isn't delivering the file.  Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164063/file-download-link-in-rails

Comment: Before I was doing this way, I used what you attached and that didn't work at all.

Comment: You mispelled **rendered** as *rednered*.

Comment: yeah that still doesn't fix it

Comment: Can you open up Fiddler?  What do you see as the response object?

Comment: I don't know Ruby but I've done something similar in MS WebApi.  In my case I return the file wrapped in an httpresponsemessage rather than the url of the file.  If you assign it to an anchor, in html or js, like <a href="api call" download="filename"> it'll download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by the function name that you want to open the PDF in a new tab, if so, you're missing the 2nd parameter. It should be:

```
window.open(response.data["path"].split("/")[1],"_blank");
```