# How to redirect URLs without format / extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 4.2 app I have a simple controller action that downloads a ZIP file:

```
class PresskitController < ApplicationController

  def download
    respond_to do |format|      
      format.zip do   
        send_data(Presskit.new, :filename => "presskit.zip")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

This URL works great: `http://www.myapp.com/presskit.zip`

Is there a way to make this URL work without the extension as well? So that clicking on `http://www.myapp.com/presskit` would also trigger the download?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Implement like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20771063/2767755 .. Look also the `type` key.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I just removed the `respond_to` and `format.zip` blocks completely which leaves me with only one line of code. Let's see if anyone can come up with an even better solution :-)

Comment: You added `type: "application/zip"` ? It is required, look again the answered link.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Yes, I did add it but forgot to mention that in my previous comment. Sorry about that. It's important indeed.

Comment: Ok, so what is the issue now? still not working?

Comment: It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `send_data` for your action? as you don't care about the format

```
class PresskitController < ApplicationController
  def download
    send_data(Presskit.new, :filename => "presskit.zip")
  end
end
```

Comment: You are right. I just had to add `type: "application/zip"` to that. I hope Arup won't mind if I mark this answer as the correct one. Even though he was a little faster :-)

Comment: I think he doesn't mind about the reputation (he's got 78'000).