# rails link_to download file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I need to add a link to download the file from assets/docs/Физика.pdf
I do not know how to do that. 
I am trying to do so here: in view -

```
<%= link_to "download", '/Физика.pdf', :download => 'filename' %>
```

I get an error message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0.pdf"
```

What am I doing wrong?
Help me please

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164063/file-download-link-in-rails).

Comment: Maybe just `<%= link_to 'download', '/assets/docs/Физика.pdf' %>` or `<%= link_to 'download', asset_path('/docs/Физика.pdf') %>`

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel your answer is the correct answer

Answer (score 9):

You can do steps as below:

**Step1**: Open file `routes.rb`

```
get 'download_pdf', to: "homes#download_pdf"
```

**Step2**: I assumed your `controller` was `home_controller.rb`, you put this line:

```
def download_pdf
  send_file "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/docs/Физика.pdf", type: "application/pdf", x_sendfile: true
end
```

**Step3**: In your `view` file.

```
<%= link_to "download", download_pdf_path %>
```

I suggest that you should put this `docs` folder in `public` folder.

For example: 
`public/docs/*.pdf`

Comment: Worked smoothly on Rails 7.

Answer (score 5):

step 1: The View

```
<%= link_to "download", download_path, target: "_blank"%>
```

step 2: Routing

```
match 'download', to: 'home#download', as: 'download', via: :get
```

step 3: Inside controller

```
send_file 'public/pdf/user.png', type: 'image/png', status: 202
```

Answer (score 2):

When placing files in `/assets` you can use the Rails helper `#asset_path`.

```
<%= link_to 'download', asset_path('/docs/Физика.pdf') %>
```

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, using the HTML download attribute in your link_to helper does the trick

```
<%= link_to "Download", file.file(:original, false), download:true %>
```

Hope this helps in the future!

Comment: you should pass filename to "download", i. e. `download: file.filename` instead of `download: true`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'download', root_path << '/assets/docs/Физика.pdf' %>
```

Comment: Did not help(
No route matches [GET] "/assets/docs/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0.pdf"

Comment: @StivenFrams did you get the solution ? I am facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me and also was the easiest:

```
= link_to "Click to download", asset_path("logo.png"), download: true
```

Comment: I will give upvotes if its not on haml or slim but html

Answer (score 0):

The documentation indicates how build a download link to attachment file,  would be like this

```
<a href="<%= user.avatar.attached? ? rails_blob_path(user.avatar, disposition: 'attachment') : '#' %>" target="_blank" download>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Rails 6 solution:

**Step 1:** Create your download route in your `routes.rb` file:

```
get 'download_pdf', to: "homes#download_pdf"
```

**Step 2:** Add the link to your `views`:

```
<%= link_to "download", download_single_path(url: 'url', file_name: 'filename') %>
```

**Step 3:** Add the action in your Controller `homes_controller.rb` where you take the params that you pass in your **link_to**:

```
def download_pdf
  require 'open-uri'
  url = params[:url]
  file_name = params[file_name]
  data = open(url).read
  send_data data, :disposition => 'attachment', :filename=>"#{file_name}.pdf"
end
```