# download file in asset folder rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, assets

How to make the ror file download?

**The file is:**

```
path: assets/docs/fd.pdf
```

**Option to do so generates an error:**

> <%= link_to 'download', asset_path('/docs/fd.pdf') %>  error No route matches [GET] "/docs/df.pdf"

help me, please

Comment: Try with relative path <%= link_to 'download', asset_path('docs/fd.pdf') %>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164063/file-download-link-in-rails