# rails 3.2 create download link NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, download, nomethoderror

I am trying to download files in my rails app. I saw [How to Create Download Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063721/how-to-create-download-link) and used in my app. But when I tried to download, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in ConfsController#download
undefined method `xml' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/confs_controller.rb:61:in `download'
```

This is confs_controller:

```
def download
  send_file @conf.xml.path, :type => @conf.xml_content_type, :filename => @conf.permalink
end
```

xml is my file. Its just a name like document in example. Now, I understand that this error appears because xml is nil. But why and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is `@conf`? here it is nil in your case so you got `undefined method `xml' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Actually I thought that, but if you look at the link I gave, it uses the @thing in the same way. Why mine is not working? Should I use self or something like that?

Comment: where is your file located in sendfile you have to put that path as a first parameters `send_file '/path/to.jpeg', :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline'` in this way

Comment: Path is depend on @conf.id `:path => ":rails_root/downloads/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension"` So, I can't do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not xml is `nil`. It is because `@conf` is `nil`. Hence it is not able to find xml for `nil` class.

Please make sure you have `@conf` object defined.

Comment: I put `<%= link_to 'Download', download_conf_path(@conf) %>` to show.html.erb and @conf in there is not nil. How can I assign @conf in show to @conf in controller?

Comment: I added `@conf = Conf.find(conf_params)` and conf_params is this: `params.require(:conf).permit( :id, :xml, other attributes) if params[:conf]` Now it says, `Couldn't find Conf without an ID` but `Request
Parameters:
{"id"=>"6"}`

Comment: I changed `@conf = Conf.find(conf_params)` to `@conf = Conf.find(params[:id])` and added `:id => @conf.id` to `link_to` at `show.html.erb` and it works now, thanks